# Segfault when trying to insert new entry into stl map member variable of static class

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, static, segmentation-fault

As title says, I'm having a trouble when trying to insert new value in map which is located in static class.

This static class is called `TaskCreator` and its purpose is to be a factory for tasks. Inside `TaskCreator`, tasks are first saved into a map, then at the start of a program, based on the input arguments, correct task is created and executed. Pretty straight forward. Every task class (also static) inherits `TaskCreator` class so the class and map should by all rules be instantiated before `REGISTER_TASK_TO_CREATOR` is called.

**task71.cpp**:

```
REGISTER_TASK_TO_CREATOR(Task71, 7.1)
REGISTER_TASK_TO_EXECUTOR(Task71, 7.1)

std::shared_ptr<TaskCreator> Task71::create()
{
    return std::shared_ptr<TaskCreator>(new Task71());
}
```

**taskcreator.h**:

```
#define REGISTER_TASK_TO_CREATOR(className, taskName) \
    bool className::_creatorRegistered = \
    TaskCreator::registerTask(#taskName, className::create());
[...]
class TaskCreator
{
[...]
    static std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<TaskCreator>> _taskMap;
[...]
}
```

**taskcreator.cpp**:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<TaskCreator>> TaskCreator::_taskMap;
[...]
bool TaskCreator::registerTask(std::string taskName, std::shared_ptr<TaskCreator> createFunc)
{
    auto it = _taskMap.find(taskName);

    if (it == _taskMap.end()) {
        _taskMap[taskName] = createFunc; // -> point of failure
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This worked before, but once I grouped source files and headers into subfolders, things went downhill. I'm using Qt Creator 4.10.2 on Win 10, and I added following things in .pro file:

```
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
[...]
    api/taskcreator.cpp \ # -> worked without api/ prefix, same for HEADERS
[...]
    tasks/task71.cpp      # -> worked without tasks/ prefix, same for HEADERS

HEADERS += \
[...]
    api/taskcreator.h \
[...]
    tasks/task71.h
[...]
INCLUDEPATH += \
    api \
    tasks
```

Now when I try to revert subfolder structure as it was before, I still get segmentation faults in the same place.

**ROOT CAUSE FOUND**

Fault wasn't directly related to project structure, it happened due to **static initialization order fiasco** where task registration over macro occurred before static variable `_taskMap` was initialized globally. Modifying product file structure probably acccentuated the issue with bad code.

I solved the issue by implementing static getter function for task map in `taskcreator.cpp` which makes declaration and initialization immediately and returns reference to now initialized taskMap as described [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use-members.html).

Comment: When and where do you *define* the `_taskMap` member?

Comment: On an unrelated note, instead of separate `find` and add operation for the map, you can use the [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) function instead. It will return a pair that can be used to see if the element was added or not, which can be used for the return value of `registerTask`.

Comment: `_taskMap` is defined as a global variable inside of taskcreator.cpp

`std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<TaskCreator>> TaskCreator::_taskMap;`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show it. And if possible please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us as well.

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.